# Searching in redis using Jedis in java

Tags: java, redis, jedis, nosql

I am using jedis to interact with redis in java language.

**Problem Background**

I am using hash to store user all information like:

```
hmset user:1 name xxx email yyy age zzz
hmset user:2 name aaa email bbb age ccc
```

Now in order to get any user data i can perform operation like:

```
hmget user:1 name email
```

**Problem**

My problem is that I want to search a user with name xxx. Now in this case I dont know the actual key. Mean I dont know I have to hit user:1 or user:2.

So how should I handle this case?

Any help would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response of [How to search in redis for hash keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470468/how-to-search-in-redis-for-hash-keys), Redis is a key-value store. So if you want to perform a search on a value in your map, either you need to maintain a manual index in Redis or use another database.

If you really want to use Redis, a possible index for your problem to search by name would be:

```
sadd name:xxx 1
sadd name:aaa 2
```

Then, you can retrieve the id of the member named `xxx` with:

```
SINTER name:xxx
```

Finally you have all you need to create the key of your map: `user:1`